# Compiling pandas from source - version conflict

Tags: python, pandas, mamba

I followed the steps described to fork, clone, and build pandas as detailed on:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/contributing.html#working-with-the-code
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/contributing_environment.html

Step 3 is where I get stuck on running on what looks like a version conflict:

```
# Build and install pandas
python setup.py build_ext -j 4. # this works ok
python -m pip install -e . --no-build-isolation --no-use-pep517  # see output below
```

Output:

```
(pandas-dev) mat@mbp pandas-mhy % python -m pip install -e . --no-build-isolation --no-use-pep517
Obtaining file:///Users/mat/Documents/td/start/prog/pandas-mhy
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in /Users/mat/mambaforge/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas==0+untagged.31878.g04ec93e) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /Users/mat/mambaforge/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas==0+untagged.31878.g04ec93e) (2022.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.1 in /Users/mat/mambaforge/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas==0+untagged.31878.g04ec93e) (2022.7)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20.3 in /Users/mat/mambaforge/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas==0+untagged.31878.g04ec93e) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Users/mat/mambaforge/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas==0+untagged.31878.g04ec93e) (1.16.0)
Installing collected packages: pandas
  Attempting uninstall: pandas
    Found existing installation: pandas 0+untagged.31878.g04ec93e
    Uninstalling pandas-0+untagged.31878.g04ec93e:
      Successfully uninstalled pandas-0+untagged.31878.g04ec93e
  Running setup.py develop for pandas
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
xarray 2023.1.0 requires pandas>=1.3, but you have pandas 0+untagged.31878.g04ec93e which is incompatible.
seaborn 0.12.2 requires pandas>=0.25, but you have pandas 0+untagged.31878.g04ec93e which is incompatible.
pyreadstat 1.2.1 requires pandas>=1.2.0, but you have pandas 0+untagged.31878.g04ec93e which is incompatible.
fastparquet 2023.2.0 requires pandas>=1.5.0, but you have pandas 0+untagged.31878.g04ec93e which is incompatible.
Successfully installed pandas-0+untagged.31878.g04ec93e
(pandas-dev) mat@mbp pandas-mhy % python
Python 3.8.16 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb  1 2023, 16:01:13) 
[Clang 14.0.6 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>> print(pandas.__version__)
0+untagged.31878.g04ec93e
```

pandas-dev is a mamba env that's been created acc. to Option 1 - using mamba.

Any ideas how to get on from here?

Many thanks in advance.

Tried:

- starting over a couple of times to rule out operational errors
- sometimes I got 1.10dev - version rather than the 0+untagged one

Comment: Did you run `python -m pip install -r requirements-dev.txt` in your virtual environment?

Comment: I did, unfortunately no change, still same problem. Thanks for your feedback though.

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into a similar issue and stumbled upon this thread: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/48060#issuecomment-1277149213

The "0+untagged..." version seems to imply that there was an issue with tags not getting downloaded and/or the depth of the clone being too shallow.